# Can perl regex only deal with limited text?

Tags: perl, ubuntu

I have been trying to match a string and output all the text after the match.

e.g: I attempt to print everything after the word "hello"

```
$string = "hello its a good day"

output: its a good day.
```

the following code has worked very efficiently:

```
my ($extract) = $string =~ /hello\s*(.+)$/;
```

The issue comes when I try use a large amount of text such as when the string is a file with hundreds of words (like a pragraph with multiple lines) and I want to only use the text after a certain word just like above. It just doesnt respond at all.

example

```
Dear sally, how is your day, I heard things are getting better
etc etc

how is everyone

sometimes. not alwyas etc etc etc etc

kind regards
```

So then I want to capture everything after "Dear sally".

the output would be:

```
, how is your day, I heard things are getting better
etc etc

how is everyone

sometimes. not alwyas etc etc etc etc

kind regards
```

I tried to use the split command instead but it just outputs numbers.

Comment: Can you show a minimal but complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"It just doesnt respond at all"* isn't very clear. A dot `.` in a regex pattern will ordinarily match any character except for a newline

Probably your input data is spread across multiple lines?

You can use the `/s` modifier to alter dot to match anything at all, but in that circumstance a pattern like `/hello\s*(.+)$/s` will match *all of the rest of the file* after `hello`

You should explain what you're trying to achieve; then we could help better

Answer (score -1):

You can try following approach:

```
my $output;

while (my $line = <$fh>)
{
    if ($output)
    {
        $output .= $line;
        next;
    }

    if ($line =~ /hello\s*(.+)/)
    {
        $output = $1;
    }
}
```

I've tested it on a 150k+ line text file and it finished in less than a second.

Basic logic here is that we go through all the lines in a file opened under `$fh` filehandle and look for a match. If match is found in a line, then we save the matched part of a line into the `$output` variable. For subsequent lines we do not perform any matching, instead we concatenate them into the `$output` variable.

After all lines have been processed, the `$output` variable contains the line that matched our search string as well as all the lines that followed.

Comment: You should really explain what your code actually does. The OP is far from clear about what they want, and throwing in a guess without asking doesn't usually help a lot. Also, no one mentioned response times and so they're irrelevant. A very ordinary hard disk drive will read 100MB in a second, so unless the data is massive (the OP said "hundreds of words", so about 10KB maximum) the read time is insignificant

Comment: @Borodin, I've added brief explanation